# Render preview of layered png images

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I want to render preview of a layered image
All the images and text  with the x any y coordinates are known from photoshop

I want to place all images at thoose positions .

Any Idea Or Any Available SDK that can help

Comment: Do you mean rendering a Photoshop (psd)  file, or several jpg and png images?

Comment: Rendering several Png Jpg and text

Comment: @cyanide Yes , Rendering several Jpg , Png And Text

Comment: @cyanide Yes , JPEG,  pngs and text .I would like to have a aditional functionality of swapping images with their own

Its urgent any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your image first in image editor software like Adobe Photoshop, and place the layer of image according to your needs. Then use **ImageView** to place that image.

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you creating your own image editing app, then you should consider these library :

1. JJIL
2. Android Image Filtering
3. Aviary SDK

Answer (score -1):

For reading Photoshop (PSD) files try JDeli:

https://www.idrsolutions.com/jdeli/

It has a class PsdDecoder. Unfortunately it isn't free.

---

Gimp and Paint.NET can open Photoshop file and they are open-source.

Comment: Thanks for your response,
But i already have a open source image editing sdk

Just need to develop this module So that a preview can be generated on users device.
Additional Functionality of swapping placeholderq images with their own will be present